# TreeNode index property by name

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

My question is the following. I need to get the `Index` of a `TreeNode` but I know just the name of this `Node`. Have you any idea, how can I get this property?

I'd like something same:

```
int treeIndex = treeView1.Nodes["myNode"].Index;
```

If it's possible please show me a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
var result = treeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name.Equals("name"));
```

then access the index inside the Result.

Comment: Tanks for everybody. This solution was the best for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define you custom Tree class.

Example using [Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView 
{
    public int this[string nodeName] {
        var found = this.Nodes.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.Text == nodeName);
        return (found == null)?-1:found.Index;
    }
}
```

and after use this like:

```
var tree = new MyTreeView(); 
...
...

var coolNodeIndex = tree["MyCoolNode"].Index;
```