# Looping through array to add each item to a parentNode

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, treeview, treenode

I have the following code:

```
TreeNode parentNode1 = new TreeNode("CONNECTING RODS");
TreeViewNav.Nodes.Add(parentNode1);

string[] subNodes =
{
    "STOCK", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",
    "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
};

foreach (var node in subNodes)
{
    parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(node);
}
```

so im basically trying to do this but in a neater way:

```
TreeNode childNodeA = new TreeNode("A");
TreeNode childNodeB = new TreeNode("B");
TreeNode childNodeC = new TreeNode("C");
TreeNode childNodeD = new TreeNode("D");
TreeNode childNodeE = new TreeNode("E");
TreeNode childNodeF = new TreeNode("F");

parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeA);
parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeB);
parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeC);
parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeD);
parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeE);
parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNodeF);
```

Im getting the error on the `parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(node);` line.
The error is

> 'string' is not assignable to paramenter type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode'

I know its because I have made the array a string array but I dont know how else to do it any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: `parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(node));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChildNodes.Add` is expecting a `TreeNode` object but you are passing it a `string`. You should:

```
foreach (var node in subNodes)
{
    parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(node));
}
```

---

With regards to adding sub-sub nodes:

```
foreach (var node in subNodes)
{
    var treeNode = new TreeNode(node);
    //Call function that returns all the sub-sub nodes
    //Assign those nodes to 'treeNode' using another foreach - or better still have this as a recursive function
    parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(treeNode);
}
```

Comment: Hmm you were fast, sorry i dint see your answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan - It is ok :) I saw that you posted it a moment after so I assumed it is the case :)

Comment: Thanks sorry to be a pain, I have a function called GetData() which is wehat I use to call the database and inside the parameters it is expecting a sql query but I dont know how to add this to the code that you have shown me

Comment: @Luke - where my comments are call your GetData method with the `node`. The result you can assign to the child's of the `treeNode`

Comment: I still dont understand how this creates a subsub node because to create the sub node I just called the parameter I put in the main node and added a child to that?

Comment: @LukeRayner - if you edit your question to include how you call GetData then I can help

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use the string of type [TreeNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529461(v=vs.85).aspx) Try this,

```
foreach (var node in subNodes)
{
    parentNode1.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(node));
}
```

Comment: I also want to add ChildNodes to those ChildNodes how would I do this?

Comment: You could fine the parent node with this , var result = treeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(node => node.Name.Equals("name"));  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279097/treenode-index-property-by-name

Comment: then do the same by calling add(new TreeNode(whatever));

Comment: @LukeRayner - If you show us how you store the values for the sub-sub nodes and how you know to make the connection between sub and sub-sub then we will be able to help better

Comment: my sub-sub nodes are going to be from a database. I have a column named [Part Number] which is what I want to use to call the data, I want to display the data on the page from a column named [Description]